# I want to create a folder and it will contain only 1 video file. Now i want os.walk to access the file and assign it to the cv2.VideoCapture

Tags: python

Is this possible?

```
Import os
Import cv2

For (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(directory):
        For file in files:
                If file.endswith(.mp4)
                    Return file

Cam = cv2.VideoCapture (file)
```

I want to run a video using opencv, but I don't want to type the filename. I want to add videos to the directory from which opencv will access the video.

The error is "assertion failed" .

Please help.

Comment: Kindly add a code snippet that you have tried and not pseudo code that you think might work.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use uppercase in your statements... Hopefully something like this could work:

```
import os

def find_mp4(directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith('.mp4'):
                return os.path.join(root, name)

directory = '.'
mp4_file_name = find_mp4(directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import os
import cv2


for root, dirs, filename in os.walk('videos'):
    for fil in filename:
        if fil.endswith('.mp4'):
            ref = os.path.join(root,fil)    # find the files and then join it with the path and assign it to a variable
            print(ref)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(ref)


while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()



    cv2.imshow("output", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(25) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```